# JavaFx sizing layouts

Tags: javafx

I'am not familiar with JavaFx so I'am trying to code my JavaFx Components in Java Controller classes and calling them in main, my problem is that I cant size my layouts with all the width of the the window, I have this simple code :

```
public Acceuil(){
        LAB_POST = new Button("Posts");
        LAB_EVENT = new Button("Evennements");
        .....
        // my two boxes
        VBox leftPane = new VBox();
        FlowPane bpane = new FlowPane();

        leftPane.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        leftPane.setSpacing(30);
        leftPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        leftPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#34495e");
        leftPane.setMinWidth(300);
        leftPane.setPrefSize(300, 600);

        bpane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;"); // to see the space that it took
        bpane.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        bpane.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        bpane.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        bpane.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

        leftPane.getChildren().addAll(TXT_SEARCH, LAB_POST....);
        this.getChildren().addAll(leftPane,bpane);


        this.setMinHeight(600);
        this.setMinWidth(900);
}
```

(Ps: I tried the FlowPane,BorderPane,AnchorPane and even Boxes)
So I'am Expecting to have the bpane in all the space that remains in my window but I get this,
[image: interface]
So I'am wondering what I need to type to let the bpane take all the space, Thank you

Comment: What type of `Parent` `Node` is `this` referencing?

Comment: Sorry I can't understand you

Comment: What `Parent` `Node` does `this`(the `Class`) extends?

Comment: nothing it's just a simple class, Whatever 'ahmed' helped me with his answer, I found his code line in many codes but I didn't knew what it does exactly.

Comment: @kleopatra I'am fine with that, it was just an example that I coded in few minutes

Comment: you might not care but should: anything that makes your code hard to read will reduce the probability to get help - why should we bother with a question that the asker didn't put any effort into? Back to your problem: reading the api doc is always a good starter ...

Comment: @kleopatra Indeed !

Comment: Given that the first part of the answer helped you, your "simple class" must extend `HBox`. I think you need to go back and learn more Java Basics. Starting with `Inheritance`. This will save you a lot of time in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Sedrick we need to know what is the container of these elements but you can try this:

```
bpane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
HBox.setHgrow(bpane, Priority.ALWAYS); // Add this line
```

Also if it is inside an AnchorPane you can try this:

```
AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(this, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(this, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(this, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(this, 0.0);
```

Comment: this is a just simple class, then I call the class in a Scene

Comment: Hbox.setHgrow(bpane, Priority.Always);
Fixed what I wanted to do, Thank you so much Ahmed